# Swipable Tabs activity and its title also swipable with back button

Tags: java, android, tabs, back-button-control

How can i display below mentioned tabs view with back button and cardview?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use back Button on a Android phone you have to `override onBackPressed()` function in an Activity or a Context.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //TODO your code goes here!
}
```

If you want to swipe between pages from your **ViewPager** you have to create a view pager and use the `index` of the pages to swipe between them.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final ViewPager mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Above mentioned code will swipe the ViewPager's page to the first page, if it is in any other page than the first one.